# HtmlUnit skips table data text after <b> tag

Tags: html-table, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit version 2.10.  I am reading data from an html table.  The cell in question contains:

```
<td colspan="2" id="num_custs_text">
    <b>Affected Customers:</b> 22
</td>
```

If I use:

```
final List<?> elements = pageHtml.getByXPath(getXPath());

     for (Object rowObject : elements) {
        (...)
        String rowDataString = rowData.asText();
        (...)
     }
```

the rowDataString **only contains "Affected Customers:"**.  **It does not contain "22"**.  I have tried dumping the entire page to a log using **pageHtml.asXml()** but the output does not contain "22".  It looks like HtmlUnit is ignoring the text after the  tag on the initial getPage operation.

How do I force HtmlUnit to load?

Thank you,

Neil

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that you have not provided the input HTML text nor the XPath you use it is impossible to determine whether you have a wrong XPath string or not. I will assume you have the right XPath string.

Now, you said:

> I have tried dumping the entire page to a log using pageHtml.asXml() but the output does not contain "22"

If that is the case, then how do you know the 22 is actually there? I will assume you have checked that in an actual web browser. Was JavaScript enabled in that browser? I will assume it was.

Then the most likely issue is that the 22 is being set by JavaScript (maybe AJAX) and HtmlUnit is failing to fetch it (or you don't have JavaScript enabled in HtmlUnit).

Were my guesses right?